# AHBottomNavigation change Behaviour with 5 items

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I am using AHBottomNavigation [This tutorail](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation)

When I use 3 items it shows name below but when i shows 5 items in bottom nav it shows only name of selected item.

[image]

Here you can check refernce image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i am posting solution of my own question which i found, it works for me hope it will be helpful to others if needed someone.

```
bottomNavigation.setForceTitlesDisplay(true);
```